# find Lim sup $X_n$ and Lim inf $X_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Question: let $X_{n}=\frac{(n-1)(-1)^{n}}{n}$ find the $\limsup(X_{n})$
  and $\liminf(X_{n})$

Can I get someone to help me with this proof? I get that $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$
   gives me $\liminf(X_{n})=\limsup(X_{n})=0$, but how does it get affected by multiplying it by $(n-1)$? How can I go from here to obtain a proof that flows?

Comment: Take the even terms and find the limsup. Take the odd to find the liminf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the $\lim \inf$ is $-1$ and the $\lim \sup $ is $1$. To prove it, remark that $-1 \leq X_n \leq 1$ and find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $X_{n_k}$ tends to $1$. Then, do the same for $-1$.

Comment: Thanks roger. so what it look like this? X_n=sup{X_k:k>=n}. picking n1=1 so m>=n_k such that X_(n_k+1)-X_m< 1/k+1? I think I am kind of lost on how to show it as a proof?

Comment: For example, the subsequence $X_{2n}$ converges to $1$, which means that $\sup \{ X_k: k \geq n \}$ is $ \geq 1$. Also $\sup \{ X_k: k \geq n \} \leq \sup_n X_n =1$ which means that the $\lim \sup$ is $1$.

Comment: thank you roger. What can I use as a sub sequence to show that it converges to -1?

Comment: Mitsos already answered this :), take for instance $X_{2n+1}$.

Comment: i see. Thank you. I'm going to try to write this out as a proof now. Hope i make sense. :)